# C# - console application, array problem

Tags: c#, console

I have problem in very simple console app, code looks like this.

int x - player moving and changing axis "x" and I want make full history of moving via array. See code(only example) below...

Thank you for your help and answer

```
  int round = 0;

  while(infinity){

  int[] PosXSave = new int[round + 1]; //theoretically infinity size of arrray.

  PosXSave[round] = x; //every round i want save current value of x, but 
                       //only last save have propertly value and rest are
                       //zero or other number

  round++

  }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question or your code. Did you mean to declare `PosXSave` before the `while`?

Comment: My god, now I tryed declare array out of while and save position working propertly. Sorry for stupid question :-(

Answer (score 1):

Using array might be bit faster, but List would be easier to use in this case.

```
List<int> history = new List<int>();
while(infinity){

 history.Add(x);

}
// round is history.count;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, problem was in declare array in while. :-)

Comment: Yeah, i know. I still wanted to point you to List. List is like array, but it automatically resizes, so you can just keep adding items